# Ranking Daily Price Changes

Tags: python, sorting, ranking, rank

I am writing an algo to rank the changes in price of a given list of stocks each day. Right now I'm working with two stocks: Apple and Amex. I would like to rank them from greatest change in price to least change in price, daily.

For example the data I have looks like this:

Day 1:

AAPL = 60.40

AMX = 15.50

Day 2:

AAPL = 61.00

AMX = 15.60

And I would like the result to look like this, with the highest positive change to be ranked fist. Is this possible?

Change:

AAPLchg = .60 Rank 1

AMXchg = .10  Rank 2

This is what I have so far:

```
def handle_data(context, data):
price_history = data.history(context.security_list, "price", bar_count=2, frequency="1d")
for s in context.security_list:
    PrevAMX = price_history[sid(679)][-2]
    CurrAMX = price_history[sid(679)][1]
    PrevAAPL = price_history[sid(24)][-2]
    CurrAAPL = price_history[sid(24)][1]
    AMXchg = CurrAMX - PrevAMX
    AAPLchg = CurrAAPL - PrevAAPL
    if AMXchg < AAPLchg:
        order(sid(679), 20)
    if AAPLchg < AMXchg:
        order(sid(24), 20)


price_history = data.history(context.security_list, "price", 20, "1d")
print price_history.mean()
print AMXchg
print AAPLchg
print log.info(str(context.chg_list.sort('adv_rank', descending=True).head()))
```

Comment: Sure there is, what have you tried so far. Right now there's too many possible answers.

Comment: context.chg_list = [AMXchg, AAPLchg]
            
    price_history = data.history(context.security_list, "price", 20, "1d")
    print price_history.mean()
    print AMXchg
    print AAPLchg
    print log.info(str(context.chg_list.sort('adv_rank', descending=True).head()))

Comment: Please edited your question to include what you tried with proper formatting, not in the comment.

Comment: Done. Please let me know how this looks.

Comment: How do I define K? It's giving me a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the prices in dictionaries, then you could do this:

```
yesterday = {
    'AAPL': 60.40,
    'AMX': 15.50,
}

today = {
    'AAPL': 61.00,
    'AMX': 15.60,
}

change = {k: today[k] - yesterday[k] for k in today}

sorted_stocks = sorted(change, key=change.get, reverse=True)

for ss in sorted_stocks:
    print('%s: %.2f' % (ss, change[ss]))
```

Comment: What do the K ,  ss and '%s: %.2f' stand for?